# Filtering for #row-details in a b-table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to display tasks in b-table and subtasks that belong to that task.
Not having lots of luck with using filter and I am not sure where to put "v-if" statement.

```
    <b-table :items="tasks" :fields="fields" responsive="sm">
        <template #cell(sub)="row">
            <b-form-checkbox v-if="checkforsubtasks(row.item.id)" @change="row.toggleDetails" ></b-form-checkbox>
        </template>
        <template #cell(task)="row">
            {{ row.item.task.length &lt; 40 ? row.item.task : row.item.task.substring(0,40) + "..." }}
        </template>
        <template #cell(priority)="row">
            <span v-if="row.item.priority === 'Critical'" class="badge badge-danger">{{ row.item.priority }}</span>
            <span v-else-if="row.item.priority === 'Significant'" class="badge badge-warning">{{ row.item.priority }}</span>
            <span v-else-if="row.item.priority === 'Moderate'" class="badge badge-success">{{ row.item.priority }}</span>
        </template>
        <template #cell(status)="row">
            <strong >{{ row.item.status }}</strong>
        </template>
        <template #cell(duedate)="row">
            {{ (row.item.duedate || "").substring(5) }}
        </template>
        <template #cell(actions)="row">
            <span  @click=" $bvModal.show('modal-newsubtask'); assignsubtask(row.item) ">
                <i class="fas fa-plus" v-b-tooltip.hover.botom title="add subtask to this task"></i>
            </span>
            <span>
                 <i class="far fa-window-maximize ml-3" v-b-tooltip.hover.botom title="maximize and see task in new window"></i>
            </span>
            
        </template>
        

        <template #row-details="row">
            <b-card >
            <b-table :items="subtasks" outlined :fields="fields" thead-class="d-none" [[ v-if="subtask.subtaskof === row.item.id" ]] responsive="sm"></b-table>


            <!-- This will sow all subtasks in this components state 
                 but I need it to show only subtasks that have subtaskof 
                 same as task.id I am showing subtasks for -->
            
            
            </b-card>
        </template>
    </b-table>
```

This will sow all subtasks in this components state but I need it to show only subtasks that have subtaskof same as task I am showing subtasks for

Answer (score 0):

I solved this

```
<template #row-details="row">
     <b-table 
        :items="subfilter(row.item)" outlined 
        :fields="fields" 
        thead-class="d-none" 
        responsive="sm"></b-table>

</template>
<script>
methods: {

subfilter(item){
      return  this.tasks.filter((mysubtask) => mysubtask.subtaskof == item.id);
  }

}

</script>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.